# Sum two column values on the basis of two name column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to Postgres database. I am given 4 columns homeTeamName, homeTeamGoals, awayTeamGoals, awayTeamName.
I want to find out the total goal(homeTeamGoals + awayTeamGoals) scored by each team.

```
select distinct hometeamname, SUM(hometeamgoals + awayteamgoals) as goals
    from worldcupsmatches

    where worldcupsmatches is not null
    group by hometeamname
order by goals desc
```

the database is as follows

[image: database here]

I think my solution is wrong. So looking for a better way

Comment: Chile won 3-0 against Mexico? awesome.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the `distinct` is completely unnecessary. But your solution looks correct (except for the useless `distinct`) . What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  output is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the table content as below, and then apply SUM function :

```sql
select teamname, sum(goals) goals
from (
  select hometeamname as teamname, hometeamgoals as goals
      from worldcupsmatches
      where worldcupsmatches is not null    
  union all
  select awayteamname, awayteamgoals
      from worldcupsmatches
      where worldcupsmatches is not null
) t
group by teamname
order by goals desc, teamname asc
;
```